# How to Redirect the user to Home Page when request any folder gwt spring?

Tags: gwt, jboss, spring-security

I have GWT Spring security 3.2.0 application, inside war file I have uploads/ images/ folders.

how I can redirect the user to the home page if the user tried to access any folder of images or uploads?

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/greet/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/uploads/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    </http>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-order the definitions and have the /** pattern as last:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/greet/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="denyAll()"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/uploads/**" access="denyAll()"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
  <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
</http>
```

Comment: I am still able to access uploads and images

Comment: Updated the answer after your clarification of the question.

Comment: if the user want to access images or  uploads I want to redirect to home page

Comment: Should it apply to only unauthenticated users, or any users?

Comment: all users must not access it

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover this, but wouldn't it then be better to move it under WEB-INF/classes/... which will guarantee you that no user can ever access that content, while still be able to work with it programatically?